# How to Make a Timer App Using Outsystems?

Tags: outsystems

There is no timer widget in Outystems that ticks like a digital clock:
00 : 00 : 00 being [hour][minutes][seconds].

I want to make a time tracking app.

Any help in the right direction will do. I can code and Im willing to put in the work. I just need a guide.

I was able to make a sample timer but I want be able to manipulate the time data.

For example 00hr 01min 20sec , I'd like to be able to use that data or print it. atleast

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are several timer widgets in the OutSystems forge. Additionally, you can build your own. Assuming you're trying to build a mobile application, you can use plain JavaScript to achieve that.

More specific than this, you'll have to edit your question so we can exactly know what you're looking for.

Cheers!